# Is my question problematic? If so, why?

Tags: discussion

The following was commented on my [post](http://%20https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/68598/is-there-a-5th-position-on-conscious-experience-interacting-with-the-physical-w?noredirect=1#comment190795_68598):

> Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and
>   that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a
>   personal attack. (philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).
>   Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring
>   them within guidelines. Additional clarification at
>   (philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com).

Is my question problematic? If so, why?

Comment: Proper link: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/68598/is-there-a-5th-position-on-conscious-experience-interacting-with-the-physical-w#comment190795_68598

Comment: This was a comment by this member.  He is not a moderator. Don’t worry even if your question is ultimately closed.  If you are here for a while you will learn the ropes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the comment because many new users are often surprised their questions can be edit or closed. There are some limits of what can and can't be asked on the site, and why there are different views, I find that having the discussion prior to voting to close helps new users understand there is a process of peer-review here. Many questions posted are duplicates, wildly idiosyncratic, or incomprehensible, and I believe it's fair to newer users to give them a head's up. While I have no objection about your speculations that consciousness can be categorized as a permutation space of verbal descriptions taken as a mapping of domain to codomain values, I think the post is adequately described as:

> Questions that push a personal philosophy with no question beyond "am I right" or "what do you think" are off-topic here as this is not a blog. It's ok to express unique opinions, but you must have an actual, answerable question to go with them.